# AWS EKS on fargate pull image results in timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I have a basic eks cluster up with a fargate profile and want to start a pod in it and get below strange error. If I open a shell from the ec2 instance I can ping google.com so there is no problem with the connection.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot. Thankful for help.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: httpd-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpd
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: httpd
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: httpd
        image: httpd
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

```
Normal  Scheduled   17 minutes ago  fargate-scheduler   Successfully assigned default/httpd-deployment-7c4cc6bf78-phgls to fargate-ip-172-31-16-16.eu-west-1.compute.internal
Normal  Pulling 12 minutes ago  kubelet Pulling image "httpd"
Warning Failed  17 minutes ago  kubelet Failed to pull image "httpd": failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/httpd:latest": failed to resolve reference "docker.io/library/httpd:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/httpd/manifests/latest": dial tcp 34.205.13.154:443: i/o timeout
```

Comment: I would guess your security group is blocking communication. Your problem is not timeout, it is not able to connect with docker hub.

Comment: thanks, but the security group outbound tab is fully open and I can also ping out from the machine.

Comment: You need inbound + outbound. Can you show the ping command you ran?